# Create my own Event in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to automate a website which has a login and a series of forms which a user is expected to fillup. I have designed my document ready condition in "if-block". However, I want this to be an event so that it works similar to `webbroswer_documentcompleted` event of default web browser control.

I want to raise an event each time that condition is fulfilled in my code.
Also, I want the event to be raised once. Till now I have only been able to raise manual events from within events (i.e. check for an event after an event has occurred).
How do i create this event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Faster_Ticket_Attempt
{
   public  class WebBrowser
   {         
      public static void Main(String[] args)
      {
          IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("SOME URL");
          if (((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"))
          {
                MessageBox.Show("we are ready");
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a delegate, which represents your event handler:

```
public delegate void YourEventHandler(<your parameters, e.g. some EventArgs>);
```

Then, you have to declare the event:

```
public event YourEventHandler YourEvent;
```

And finally, to raise the event, you just call it (but check, if any event handler is attached to it, first):

```
if (YourEvent!= null)
    YourEvent(<your event parameters>);
```

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8627sbea.aspx

Comment: Doesn't your code manually call an event? Here i want the event to be fired each time the document is completed automatically

Comment: No, it raises the event. Any listener can now receive your event by adding a handler to it: WebBrowser.YourEvent += anyEventReceiver;

Answer (score 0):

```
(static) event Action webbroswer_documentcompleted;

(static) void webbroswer_documentcompleted_handler()
{
   ... do something
}
```

somewhere in your code type :

```
webbroswer_documentcompleted += webbroswer_documentcompleted_handler;
if(condition) webbroswer_documentcompleted();  // throw your event here
```

Change delegate Action to other delegate for example EventHandler in case you need event handler to accept arguments.

You can also use lambda operators, like this :

```
webbroswer_documentcompleted += () = >
{
   ... do something
};
```

Comment: Unfortuantely your code works only one time to check if document has completed loading.However i need to work on several different URLs. In my question i stated i need to fill series of forms.It checks for **document_completed** only for first URL

Comment: Event is fired whenever you fire it in your code. I only gave you an example of how you can use events... May be you should use instance event rather than static one (that belongs to class itself not to object). It depends on how your program works.

Comment: what i wanted to do here is to create my own event which works just like **webbrowser_documentcompleted** (of Web Browser Control) and instead of calling it manually in my code i want it to be raised automatically  based upon predefined conditions.

Comment: What you would like to do is to extend the existing Web_Browser_Control class with new event and make it automatically fire whenever certain conditions are met ? Don't believe it's possible. In c# you can use extension methods but not an extension events. What you can do here is add new class like EventMonitor that runs in separate thread and fires events when conditions are met.